# Save users token to a db and then comment using open graph

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, token

I want to make a desktop application using facebook c# sdk, where i have a login form, and each time a user in this same computer makes login and gives permission to my app, that it stores its auth credentials (userid and token ?) to a db. In the end of the day, i push a button in my app, and it makes all users in the db to leave a pre-defined comment in my page, using Opengraph. Is it possible ?

Comment: "is it possible"?  What have you tried, and what issues have you run into?  Please edit the question to add this information.  And I don't think this is the correct way to store user authorization.  I think you're supposed to write an app that requests offline access, otherwise their tokens will (should) expire.

Comment: I've not tried because i need to know first if its possible before starting this big project, because the project liability depends if i can or not store user authorization. Can i ?

Comment: It isn't so big that a prototype wouldn't eke out the details.  I can tell you this with confidence because my team did exactly that workflow for a similar FB application - prototype, stumble around a bit (due to the FB docs being hard to use for new users), googled a lot, and found out a solid answer within a day and a half.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, (from what I have been reading over the past few days, Facebook Documenation isnt great and I'm having my own Facebook related issue) even if you request offline access the token's still expire, it just means that your app can get token's while the user is offline, so you would just need to store the userid, appid, and app secret.

Comment: In relation to Merlyn's comment.